# QWidget (a qlineedit) auto resize to content

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Below Code successfully auto-resizes QLineEdit field as needed (new width/height based on dynamic text). Now in order to make the resized QLineEdit fit the container widget, I do `adjustsize()`  on the container widget.

Relevant elements in my code:

```
void theContainer::resize_to_content(QString text) {
{
// ...
lineedit.setFixedSize(calcualtedWidth, calculatedHigh);
theContainer::adjustSize();
}
```

the problem encountered is that even though both resizings of the QLineEdit and the parent widget work (to some extent), the limitation in this case is that  the QlineEdit, after resizing, overlaps adjacent widgets!
It looks like that container widget -- when it adjusts -- seems to ignore other non manipulated children ...
Is there a systematic way to prevent such overlapping ?? not just a workaround I mean.

-- Widgets before adjustments

[image]

-- Widgets after text change and size adjustments:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure using the classes Qt provides specifically for layout management will help.

See [Qt documentation on layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

If it won't, I think you could resize the entire window to get more space instead of only the parent widget.

Comment: Notice that adjustsize() is actually doing that  (resize entire window).